# Bluetooth device is getting connected automatically even after passing false to connectGatt

Tags: android, sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am connecting the bluetooth device using below statement:

```
 val gatt: BluetoothGatt? = device.connectGatt(
        mContext, false, mBluetoothGattCallback, TRANSPORT_LE
    )
```

Device is getting disconnected by BLE stack, so as per my requirement(In some case) I need to reconnect the same device so I am storing gatt object at global level and using it like below to connect the device again.

```
 gatt?.connect() //Reconnect the same device
```

But here the problem is some time before calling this statement device is getting connected automatically.

Can any one please let me know why device is getting connected automatically even after passing autoConnect as false?